# Invalid api key for get data with CI andREST Server

Tags: php, rest, api, codeigniter, web-services

My problem is i dont know where must i put api key.
I can do it if I test on postman, but on my code i cannot. maybe someone can help me?

If i using postman i can get all data
[image: postman]

But i got error if i try on my php, if i dont use require apikey i can get all data.
[image: php]

this is my script

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script allowed');
class Kontak extends MY_Controller{
    var $api = "";

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->api = $this->config->item('api');
    }

    function index(){
        $data['dataKontak'] = json_decode($this->curl->simple_get($this->api.'/kontak&auth-apikey=[123456]'));
        $this->load->view('kontak/list', $data);
    }
```

this is my results if i dont use apikey
[image]

and i just use this code

```
function index(){
    $data['dataKontak'] = json_decode($this->curl->simple_get($this->api.'/kontak'));
    $this->load->view('kontak/list', $data);
}
```

Comment: If it's the lib I think you're using, `$this->curl->header('auth-apikey', $key);`

Comment: where must I put that code? can u explain it to me? so i can test it

Comment: Try adding this line before making the api request. before this line `$data['dataKontak'] = json_decode($this->curl->simple_......` in `function index()`

Comment: I got the same error. I have changed my code according to your answer like this : function index(){ $this->curl->header('auth-apikey', '123456');$data['dataKontak'] = json_decode($this->curl->simple_get...... }

Answer (score 0):

You could append the custom header parameters as the second argument, like this :

```
function index(){
    $data['dataKontak'] = json_decode($this->curl->simple_get($this->api.'/kontak', array(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'auth-apikey: 123456'))));
    $this->load->view('kontak/list', $data);
}
```

Comment: i have found the answer I just need to give this $this-> api. '/kontak?auth-apikey='123456' . But this only works on GET method. I cannot use this code on POST method. and btw i'm trying to use ur code, but dont work

Comment: to use post method, you could try it like : `$this->curl->simple_post($this->api.'/kontak', array(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('auth-apikey: 123456')));`

Comment: I copied and placed what you wrote. But, still not working, is there a problem with my code?

Comment: I can't really tell without knowing what error message you get, or maybe that I'm wrong too